# Updating User Data in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've been having a problem trying to update data from a logged in user. I have the uid, but there has to be a connection between the uid and the collection of users, so that the program picks the right user to update, but I don't know how to make it.

Here's what I have:

```
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
//
double _latitude;
double _longitude;

void getCurrentLocation() async {
  try {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    setState(() {
      _latitude = position.latitude;
      _longitude = position.longitude;
    });
    _firestore
      .collection('users')
      .document('${loggedInUser.uid}')
      .updateData({'location': GeoPoint(_latitude, _longitude)});
  } catch (e) {
      print(e);
  }
}
```

Here's what I've been getting:

```
E/flutter ( 9187): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/app-#####/databases/(default)/documents/users/CGyByl58ELc0zirlVjJpv5OWAc42, null)
```

So it is using the right uid ("CGyByl58ELc0zirlVjJpv5OWAc42")

Here's a screenshot from the **Authentication** tab of Firebase:
[image]

But what I'm trying to get is the name of the collection of this user in the database:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user id is different than the document id, that's why you get that error since no document exists with the `userId`. You need to use the `userId` as the document id:

```
void addUser() async{
  var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(
  {
    "age" : 38,
  }).then((_){
    print("success!");
  });
}
```

Now you will have the `userId` as the document id and you can update the document using the `userId`

Comment: I think that this is the same as what I have but instead of using my **FirebaseUser loggedInUser;**, you're using **firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();** @Peter Haddad

Comment: @EliasMarrero The difference is that you're using `updateData` while he is using `setData`. You can not update a data that does not exist

Comment: The thing is that `setData` creates a new document with that location, and what I'm trying to do is to update the location of an existing user. @JideGuru

Comment: But you already created the users with wrong id generated, right? you might want to recreated the user with the correct id

Comment: Yes as said in the answer, you need to create the document but using the userid as the document id, same as in the answer and then your update code will work... Now according to your image you are just generating a random id instead of using the userID as the document id...